# Hash(#) Link Causes Content To Jump - Why?

Tags: html, css

Ok, so usually I'm pretty good with CSS. But this one... I can't quite wrap my ahead around why it's occurring.

I did find a couple of 'quick fixes', but I don't want to just do something for the sake of doing something, so if anyone can help me understand this anomaly, please come forward (I've tried searching the web high and low, and can't find anything about this)!!

The issue occurs when using hash(#)/anchor links. I've put together a Fiddle to better explain what's happening.

First, go here: http://jsfiddle.net/GKCE6/5/show. Looks good, right?

Now lets add the hash(#) symbol to the URL: http://jsfiddle.net/GKCE6/5/show/#some-content. The header just disappears! Gone! Nada!!

Any ideas? I noticed that if I remove the `overflow:hidden` rule from the `div#container`, the header comes back. The project I'm working on, though, needs the `overflow:hidden` rule to eliminate horizontal scrolling. I could probably do something like `overflow-x:hidden`, but like I said in the beginning, I would rather try to understand why this is happening so I can determine the appropriate fix.

Anyone else run into this before?

*Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GKCE6/5*

Comment: I find it highly troubling that people call that a "hashtag" now... :(

Comment: I agree @DoorknobofSnow - not sure why I did that. I edited the question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is the fixed height on the `#container`. The content is greater than the `1000px` you had set. When the page is jumping to the `#content` section its moving down the browser focuses on the content section which fills the entire `1000px`. If you set `height:auto` on the `#container` it'll work. This will allow you to keep the `overflow: hidden`

Comment: +1, beat me to it! Also, could change `height: 1000px;` to `min-height: 1000px;`

Comment: Hey man, thanks for looking into it! There's still a small issue in FF (which is where this issue originated from), but I'm opening up [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175992/top-of-page-slightly-cutoff-when-using-hashtag-anchor-links-ff-only) since you took the time to answer this one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the overflow:hidden; You want this

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

Otherwise they won't be able to read anything on your site.. The overflow-x will stop the horizontal scrolling.