# Top of Page Slightly Cutoff When Using Hashtag/Anchor Links (FF Only)

Tags: html, css

This is part 2 of this question: [Hash(#) Link Causes Content To Jump - Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175632/hashtag-link-causes-content-to-jump-why).

The root issue is actually something that's only occurring in FireFox (my apologies for not bringing this up in the original question). When I put together the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKCE6/10), I thought I had recreated it cross-browser, but even with the fix that was suggested by [SkyOut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1299385/skyout), the issue is still not resolved in FF.

Here's the original: http://jsfiddle.net/GKCE6/10/show

And here's the version with the hashtag in the URL: http://jsfiddle.net/GKCE6/10/show/#some-content.

This time it's a bit harder to notice, but you can see that 'A link' is slightly cutoff at the top (just on FF). I removed the `height: 1000px` rule from the original Fiddle, just to verify that, while the issue gets fixed on Chrome, there's still a similar issue in FF.

Any ideas?

*Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GKCE6/10*

***UPDATE 1/17/2014*** I actually found the problem - seems like it's a result of the height property in the 'clearfix' that's being used. If you compare this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKCE6/21/show/#some-content) with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKCE6/23/show/#some-content) (in FF), you'll see what I mean. Removing the `height:0` fixes it. Any idea why that would be breaking FF in this one, tiny instance?

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Took a look at your fiddle again and this time I updated it with a few changes. 
http://jsfiddle.net/GKCE6/12/

I took the off all of the set widths that you had, which will make it more fluid/responsive to the screen size. Also your nav was collapsing because of the floated elements inside of it, so I added a clear class and cleared the floats in your nav.

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em 0 0.2em;
    display: block;
}
nav h2 {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
nav a {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}
#content:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#content {
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

}

.clear {
   clear:both;
}
```

Comment: I wrote it quick to illustrate the issue. Not sure what you're seeing that is 'quite a bit wrong'. Also, I'm not worried about how far it is from the right of the page, I'm talking more about how it gets cutoff at the top when the hashtag is in the URL.

Comment: Thanks @natewiley. I actually found the problem - seems like it's a result of the height property in the 'clearfix' that's being used. If you compare this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKCE6/21/show/#some-content) with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKCE6/23/show/#some-content) (in FF), you'll see what I mean. Removing the `height: 0` fixes it. Now, the challenge is that for this specific project I can't really touch that piece. Any idea why that would be breaking FF in this one, tiny instance? Hmmmm...